# Mongoose text search - changing its behaviour to AND operation slows it down

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I am working on a search feature in which I have to perform search operation in about 300,000 documents. 
For this I have created a compound index over four fields and have given weight to them as well. By default if I search for a phrase having multiple words then mongoose searches for all the keywords with **OR** operation. Eg:- If you search for **small cell lung** then mongoose will search all document in which either one of these is available.
It is working very fast.

But my requirement is to perform **AND** operation. To achieve this I split all the words in a phrase and then put them in double quotes.So when user searches for a phrase having multiple words, search operation is performed as **AND** operation on each word. Eg:- If you search for **small cell lung** ("small" "cell" "lung")  then it should find all those documents in which all are available. It is also working but it is very slow now.

Is there any way to make it faster. 
I will share the code if required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Give a shot to this** :

`db.table.find("text", {search:"\"small\" \"cell\" \"lung\""})`

*Now above code will do the following* :

> If the search string includes phrases, the search performs an AND with
>   any other terms in the search string; e.g. search for "\"kiss me on
>   \" cheeks lips" searches for "Kiss Me on" and ("cheecks" or
>   "lips").

*You can read it from here*:

[Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases)

Comment: yes, I am using the way that you have mentioned but it slows down the search speed. So I am facing an issue with the speed. This is a code I am using:--
$text: { $search: searchData} where searchData = "small" "cell" "lung"

Answer (score 0):

When you want to match the complete phrase, enclose the phrase in escaped double quotes:

```
db.table.find( { $text: { $search: "small cell lung" } } )
```

Also see the [$text documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) on the mongodb site

Comment: yes, I know about it but I don't have to search for a complete phrase. I have to search those document in which these three can be available in any order . So I convert it to "small" "cell" "lung" and it is working as I want but it is very slow.